# How do I add a dependency to an existing service?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, services, windows-services

Hi there I was researching a problem for a program I have on my computer. The program relies on the SSDP Discovery service to be started first BUT it is not added as a dependency...

I would like to add SSDP Discovery as a dependency to this service so it will start up after SSDP Discovery starts and avoid the issue I am having.

How do I add a dependency to an existing service?

I am currently running Windows 7 SP1 Home Premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the service key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services` add a DependsOnService value appending the service short name.  See this example from Terminal Services

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TermService]
"DependOnService"=hex(7):52,00,50,00,43,00,53,00,53,00,00,00,54,00,65,00,72,00,\
  6d,00,44,00,44,00,00,00,00,00
```

Translated values

```
RPCSS
TermDD
```

Comment: A reboot probably wouldn't hurt, but unsure if is needed.  Report back.

Comment: Cool! That worked perfectly... I edited a DepondOnService key and added in the "SSDPSRV" service name. Now let's hope this actually fixes the problem I was having lol. Have a good day!